# Find uniqueness in data frame withe rows NA?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, uniqueidentifier, substitution

I have a data frame like below. I would like to find unique rows (uniqueness). But in this data I have 'NA'. I like if all value in one row with NA value is the same with other rows (like rows: 1,2,5) I want to ignore it, but if not same (like rows : 2,4) I like to keep it as unique row.
For example, in rows 1 ,2 and 6 all values except NA are the same so because NA can be value '1 and 3' I like to remove this row and just keep row 2.
Also, in row 6 values 2 and 3 (exclude NA) are the same as row c2 and c5 and there is possible NAs in c6 get same value like as c2 and c5, so this row is not unique.

Also, @ Sotos solution help me more but in last part after removing NA when make pattern for rows , his solution consider same pattern (23) for c8 and c6 and remove them. But actually c8 is unique.

data:

```
      a1  a2   a3   a4
c1    2    1    3   NA
c2    2    1    3    3
c3    2    1    4    3
c4    2    2    3   NA
c5    2    1    3    3
c6    2    NA   3   NA
c7    2    NA   0   NA
c8    2    3   NA   NA
```

I would like to have this output:

output:

```
     a1    a2  a3   a4
c2    2    1    3    3
c3    2    1    4    3
c4    2    2    3   NA
c7    2    NA   0   NA
c8    2    3   NA   NA
```

Comment: so NAs are wildcards when checking for dups?

Comment: you can use `hclust` to visually see  the similarity: `plot(hclust(dist(your_data_frame)))`

Comment: Mehrad@ Thanks for plot , it is nice plot with good information

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr) 
df <- unique(df)
#paste rows omitting NAs
df$new <- apply(df, 1, function(i) paste(na.omit(i), collapse = ''))
#use str_detect to determine whether each pattern is found more than once
df$new2 <- rowSums(sapply(df$new, function(i) str_detect(i, df$new)))
new_df <- subset(df, df$new2 == 1)
new_df <- new_df[, !names(new_df) %in% c('new', 'new2')]
new_df
#   V2 V3 V4 V5
#2  2  1  3  3
#3  2  1  4  3
#4  2  2  3 NA
```

Testing the code with the additional row as per your comment:

```
new_df
#   a1 a2 a3 a4
#c2  2  1  3  3
#c3  2  1  4  3
#c4  2  2  3 NA
#c7  2 NA  0 NA
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(a1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), a2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), a3 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L), 
    a4 = c(NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("a1", "a2", 
"a3", "a4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("c1", "c2", 
"c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7"))
```

Comment: Thanks Sotos for your solution. This is work good but if I have  a more data like : c7 <- c(2,NA,0,NA) . this solution dos not give me this row as unique. Can you help me in this way?

Comment: @tob, I added the data I used. Try it with the data I used and let me know what happens

Comment: btw, I edited the code slightly so recopy and paste it

Comment: @ Sotos, my problem is here. when we use na.omit and make pattern, we lose similar pattern even if there is unique row . for example: if we add another row " c8 <-  2  3 NA NA "  . The pattern of this row is similar to row 6 and both of them remove from output  but row 8 is unique and we should observe in output.

Comment: ok, we can do something with the NA indexes but I don't have time now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please help me whenever you are free?

Comment: should row 6 (c6) be in the final output?

Comment: No, it look likes c2 because value 2 and 3 are same with c2 and NAs in c6 can get same value as c2 .

Comment: Ok, it just got way more complicated. You need to clarify things like that in your question and include such cases in your example.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to :

1) Take all unique solutions in row that do not have a NA.

2) Among those that have NAs, see if the rest of the values is identical to another row

#### Reproduce data

```
df<-data.frame(V1 = rep(2,times = 6),
    V2 = c(1,1,1,2,1,NA),
    V3=c(3,3,4,3,3,3),
    V4=c(NA,3,3,NA,3,NA))
```

#### Create two unique data frames (one with NAs, the other without

```
df1<-unique(df[apply(df,MARGIN=1,FUN =function(z) sum(is.na(z)))==0,])
df2<-unique(df[apply(df,MARGIN=1,FUN =function(z) sum(is.na(z)))>0,])
```

#### Add rows from NAs matching your condition

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  vec<-df2[i,] 
  w<-is.na(vec)
  if(nrow(merge(vec[!w],df1[,w]))>0){ ###I remove columns where you have NAs
    df1<-rbind(df1,vec)
  }

}
```